# Let $X, Y$ be vector fields on a manifold $M$. Show, that $XY$ is not a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields

Let $X, Y$ be vector fields on a manifold $M$. Show, that $XY$ is not a vector field

---

**My attempt**

My idea would be to directly show, that

$$XY (fg) \neq (XY f)g + f(XY g) \quad \lor \quad XY (\alpha f + \beta g) \neq \alpha XY f + \beta XY g$$

I am not sure at writing out $XY (fg)$

$$XY (fg) = X ( Y (fg)) = X ((Yf)g + f(Yg)) = X((Yf)g) + X(f(Yg)) = $$

$$ = (X (Y f))g + (Yf)Xg + (Xf)(Yg) + f (X(Yg)) = (XYf)g + (Yf)Xg + (Xf)Yg + f(XYg)$$

So we get an additional $(Yf)Xg + (Xf)Yg$, thus $XY (fg) \neq (XY f)g + f(XY g)$

Which is enough to show that $XY$ is not a vector field. Are my calculations alright? I'm not sure especially because at the end, I simply ignore the brackets i.e. $(X(Yf))g$ becomes $(XYf)g$ so it can fit into our first assumption. I don't know if we can do that

Comment: Hints: You have to add extra assumptions on your vector fields, to ensure that there is a point $p$ where they are both nonzero. Given that, you continue the analysis using only the values $X(p)$ and $Y(p)$. Now, the problem is purely local and you can work in $R^n$. Can you find the functions $f, g$ assuming that $p=0$ and $X(p), Y(p)$ are both coordinate vectors? Or linearly dependent vectors?

Comment: To emphasize a point implicit in Moishe's comment, the additional term $(Yf)Xg + (Xf)Yg$ does not necessarily mean $XY$ is not a vector field - it could a priori be the case that $(Yf)Xg + (Xf)Yg$ happens to be zero for any $X,Y,f,g$.  You need to actually construct $f$ and $g$ showing that $(Yf)Xg + (Xf)Yg\neq 0$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito But we cannot construct such an $f$ and $g$ that $(Yf)Xg + (Xf)Yg \neq 0$ as long as we don't know $X$ and $Y$? If we say that $X = Y = \frac{d}{dt}$, then of course, if $f(t) = g(t) = t$, then we'd have proven that $XY$ is *not always* a vector field. But we can't prove it that for any vector field $X$ and $Y$, the composition $XY$ is not a vector field? Because, how in the end are we supposed to know in which way $X$ and $Y$ works on $f$ and $g$?

Comment: You're right that I misspoke:  Given arbitrary $X$ and $Y$, you cannot necessarily construct $f$ and $g$.  For example, if $X$ or $Y$ is the zero vector field, then constructing $f$ and $g$ is hopeless.  To show that in general $XY$ isn't a vector field, it's enough to find a single example of $X,Y,f,g$ with for which the expression is non-zero.  (On the other hand, if there is a point $p$ for which both $X(p)$ and $Y(p)$ are non-zero, then you *can* find $f$ and $g$.)

Comment: I'd work in coordinates. When you write $X = \sum_{i}X^i\partial_i$, $Y = \sum_{j}Y^j\partial_j$, you'll see that $XY$ has some 2nd order partial terms which might not be $0$, depending on $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to make my first hint explicit: The claim you are trying to prove is (in general) false. As an example, take any smooth manifold $M$ and the vector fields $X=0$ and $Y$ arbitrary. Then for every smooth function $f$ on $M$,
$$
XY(f)=0,
$$
which implies that in this example $XY=X$, is a vector field.

In case you simply forgot to assume that both vector fields $X, Y$ are nonzero, here is another example. Suppose that $M$ has two connected components $M_1, M_2$ and you have vector fields $X, Y$ on $M$ such that $X$ restricts to $0$ on $M_1$ and $Y$ restricts to $0$ on $M_2$. Then again
$$
XY(f)=0
$$
for every smooth function $f$ on $M$. Hence, again, $XY$ is the zero vector field.

So, what are the missing assumptions in your question?

**Edit.** Here a correct statement (which, IMHO, your professor should have assigned):

For every manifold nonempty $M$ and two vector field $X, Y$ on $M$ the following are equivalent:

1. The composition $XY$ is a vector field.
2. The composition $XY$ is zero vector field.
3. The tensor-field $X\otimes Y$ is zero.

Thus, taking any vector fields $X, Y$ on $M$ **not** satisfying (3) (such vector fields exist on every nonempty manifold) one obtains an example where the composition of two vector fields is not a vector field.

The missing assumption in your homework is:

There exists a point $p\in M$ such that $X(p)\ne 0$ and $Y(p)\ne 0$.

Comment: The exercise literally reads: "Prove that, if X and Y are vector fields, the composition XY is not a vector field". There are **no** further assumptions, like that X and Y should be nonzero. I honestly think that what our Prof is asking us to do is to prove that $XY$ is *not always* a vector field (by presenting a counterexample). His exercises are known to miss a lot of important assumptions, and then he's baffled why we're doing his exercises in the wrong way

Comment: @user: This is for you to figure out by talking to your instructor. If you do not know what your question exactly means, how would I (or anybody else at MSE) know?

Comment: Also, if you think that your instructor just wants you to give one example where  is not a vector field, then you already know how to do so (as it's clear from your comments under the OP).

Comment: @MoisheKohan: $\Bbb R^2$ and $X$ a constant vector field is also another one?

Comment: @C.F.G: I do not understand your example, feel free to add another answer.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I thought $\Bbb R^2$ with $X=\partial_x$ and any $Y$ satisfies in $XY=0$ but it is not true.